# File size of image in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, filesize

I need to calculate the file size of an image in Wordpress. I retrive the image url with this function:

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
```

and with

```
<?php echo $image[0]; ?>
```

I print the image url.

How can I do to retrieve the filesize and to print it?

[Here](http://pastebin.com/Yrm4rcku) is the feed-rss2.php file

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
$img = get_headers($image[0], 1);
echo $img["Content-Length"]/1024;
```

The above will print the size of the image in kb.

Comment: Yes, it works! But I need it in bytes, I forgot to mention it

Comment: Remove the "/1024" to display it on bytes.

Comment: I'll correct me, it doesn't show the exact size. It outputs a number that it isn't the size. As you can see here: http://www.primapaginaonline.it/feed/ In the source code the length parameter of the <enclosure> tag is what is printing

Comment: When I use the above code with http://www.primapaginaonline.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/sant-anna-monteprandone.jpg that image it displays 122127 bytes.

Comment: Well, I don't know what to say, i'll edit the first post with the code of the feed-rss2.php file that outputs the rss feed

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure why that is happening.

Comment: I think that I have understood why. The content-type is text/html, so it takes in input the image url as text and not the image itself

Comment: I don't really think this would be an efficient way of getting this data. Is this not stored anywhere in the wordpress database? Its definitely a workaround for now.

Answer (score 0):

*You can also use*

```
echo filesize(get_attached_file($image->ID)).'Bytes';
```